# Use the cleveref package to refer to enumerate items without the prefix "item"

Tags: cleveref

I am trying to use the `cleveref` package to refer to a particular item within an `enumerate` environment. Furthermore, I am using the `enumitem` package to enumerate the items by letter ((a), (b), ...).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
Text.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item{first}\label{item:list:first}
  \item{second}\label{item:list:second}
  \item{third}\label{item:list:third}
\end{enumerate}
The second item is \cref{item:second}.

\end{document}
```

... which gives this output:

[image: enumerate]

Is there a relatively simple way to reference only "(b)" and not "item (b)" (i.e., without the prefix "item")? In other words, I would like the output to be the following:

> The second item is (b).

Comment: Why do you even use `\cref` here? Common `\ref` would do.

Comment: @ivankokan - The macro `\labelcref` of the `cleveref` package can take multiple inputs, just like `\cref`. That's not the case for `\ref`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You asked,

> Is there a relatively simple way to reference only "(b)" and not "item (b)"

Short answer: "Yes". Long answer: Use `\labelcref` instead of `\cref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,cleveref}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item{first}\label{item:first}
  \item{second}\label{item:second}
  \item{third}\label{item:third}
\end{enumerate}
The second item is \labelcref{item:second}.
\end{document}
```

---

Here's an excerpt from p. 7 of the user guide of the `cleveref` package, with more information about `\labelcref`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{enumi}{\unskip}{\unskip}
\begin{document}

\noindent%
Text.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item{first}\label{item:list:first}
  \item{second}\label{item:list:second}
  \item{third}\label{item:list:third}
\end{enumerate}
The second item is \cref{item:list:second}.

\end{document}
```

[image]